# C# try/catch not working as expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework, try-catch, windows-console

I am working on a console app for daily imports into our CMS from a parent ERP system.
I am having a funky issue with try/catch blocks. Errors are happening inside my try's and not making it to the catch. At first, it did go into the catch and I was able to figure out the issue, but now it's just erroring on the try and staying there. Hitting continue doesn't work, just keeps showing the error again and again. The error has to do with EF and one of the models not having a required field...

```
     public void Save()
    {
        try
        {
            _context.SaveChanges(); <--bombs here and never lets me step thru
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the *exact* exception? Is it a `DbEntityValidationException`?

Comment: Try adding a `catch(Exception e)` block and put a breakpoint in there. The exception might not be of type `DbEntityValidationException`.

Comment: Have you tried to replace DbEntityValidationException with a more general exception class like "Exception"?

Comment: What's the type of the exception that happens? If it's not `DbEntityValidationException` (or derived from it), your `catch` won't be hit.

Comment: Voting to close as this is a case of a simple typographical error (catching the wrong exception)

Comment: No, its wasn't a typographical error. I was specifically trying to catch an EF error when I really needed to use the generic 'exception'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably throwing more or a different exception.
Try using

```
catch (Exception e)
```

And see if it now enters the catch and log your exception to know exactly what you are getting

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a combination of visual studio debugging settings and the fact that there is another type of exception (not found on inheritance hierarchy under DbEntityValidationException).

Please try to handle using a more general exception, even use:

```
catch (Exception ex)
```

Note: if your debugger just stops in a place where an error occured, you might find this link usefull: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx